# Flask-Mail not sending emails, no error is being reported

Tags: flask

All, I'm trying to setup flask-mail to send notifications to my email when a user registers. 
I'm getting no error messages from the script used to send the email, but nothing is actually being sent, or at least, nothing is being received.

Is there a log file which can show if an email was sent, rejected, or maybe if there was even a problem logging onto the server? How does on track this problem?

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`Flask-Email` use `smtplib` which can set debug level: https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-mail/blob/master/flask_mail.py#L139. You can set it with `MAIL_DEBUG = True` or `DEBUG = True`. Also check that `MAIL_SUPPRESS_SEND = False` and `TESTING = False`.

With debug I can see in `stdout` mail progress: success, fail, recipients and etc.

See details: http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/#configuring-flask-mail.

Comment: `app.config['TESTING'] = False` fixed.. by default mails will not be sent.. and we need to disable testing.. oh God.. I wasted almost half a day.. finding out this.. Thanks..

Comment: whattt.. seriously? I too wasted hours. Do `app.config['TESTING'] = False`

Answer (score 5):

tbicr has the most likely fix, check MAIL_SUPPRESS_SEND first.

What ended up burning me (being new to flask) is that when you instantiate your Mail() object, be sure it's ***after*** you've set your app.config values.  The Mail() object doesn't go back and look at these values after the fact, so they will default to bad values.  What's frustrating is that you won't see any errors when you try to send messages with the default/bad values.  At least not as of my posting.

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is from a while ago, but I just ran into the same issue. Like @tbicr mentioned make sure that `app.testing` is set to `False`. As it states in the `Flask-Mail`docs [here](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/#unit-tests-and-suppressing-emails):

"If the setting `TESTING` is set to `True`, emails will be suppressed. Calling `send()` on your messages will not result in any messages being actually sent."

This was exactly my problem. I implemented Google reCAPTCHA into one of my forms and the `app.testing` was set to `True` so I did not have to hit the reCAPTCHA box every time. By removing the `app.testing` or by setting it to `False`, the emails were able to be sent.